# CUDA: Synchronize global memory writing & reading with compute capability 1.1

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpgpu

Well, found the solution on nVidia forums (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/458062/atomicadd-float-float-atomicmul-float-float-/).

Thanks.

Comment: As you have Compute 1.1 GPU, you can serialize simultaneous writes to the same memory location by using atomic operations.

Comment: CUDA programming guide 3.1 - B.11.1.1:

_The floating-point version of atomicAdd() is only supported by devices of compute capability 2.0._

Comment: @eg141840 sgar91 didn't say you should use atomicAdd, he said atomic operations (_hint_ any atomic operation can be implemented based on atomicCAS() _hint_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization can be achieved by using [Atomic Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions).

Compute Capability 1.1 does not support atomicAdd() for floating point numbers but any atomic operation can be implemented based on atomicCAS() (Compare And Swap).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this code is a mess of repetitive garble that'd make debugging quite painful. Work out which sub-expressions are redundant and separate them into different variables, so that your code becomes more legible. Otherwise, it makes about as much sense to ask for help regarding this code as it'd make to ask for help winning the lottery. Nobody's going to bother reading your code because it's an eyesore.

Get a single-threaded solution running. Use a profiler to determine which parts of this code would be best exposed to parallelisation, otherwise your optimisation is just guesswork which you can't put in measurable terms. I would guess that once you have the single-threaded solution running, you might get fairly good performance from running that same solution, in parallel, on each core, on an independant range of values so there's virtually no need for synchronisation.